# Check whether a certain file type/extension exists in directory

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How would you go about telling whether files of a specific extension are present in a directory, with bash?

Something like

```
if [ -e *.flac ]; then 
echo true; 
fi
```

Answer (score 145, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

count=`ls -1 *.flac 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
if [ $count != 0 ]
then 
echo true
fi
```

Comment: Hey Thomas, how about adding a better solution to the question instead of just a downvote.

Comment: Also Thomas, your example of why not to use it is using `ls -l`, my answer uses `ls -1`

Comment: And, this answer isn't parsing the output, it is just counting the lines output, and I'm almost certain even if there are strange characters in a filename, `ls -1` is going to print one line per file

Comment: Counting lines _is_ parsing. And it will return an incorrect number if any files contain `\n` (and yes, that is valid in file names).

Comment: Pray tell us then, what magical character would have to be in a file's name in order to make the line count naught?

Comment: Maybe a bit late, but for completeness, `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -name *.flac | wc -l`. This is in accordance to ShellCheck SC2012.

Comment: @Stefan, don't forget to quote `"*.flac"` otherwise you get errors like "find: possible unquoted pattern after predicate `-name'?"

Comment: In case directory contains very large number of files it will throw an error `Argument list too long`

Comment: You should probably add `-q` or `-b` (or `--hide-control-chars` and `--escape` respectively) to substitute control characters with `?` or escape them as octals – then you will be safe with line breaking filenames.

Comment: Also you could pass `ls` output through `head` to skip unnecessary counting of all lines, if the output is large, so you would get: `any_exists="$(ls -q1 2>/dev/null | head -n1 -q | wc -l)"` – the funny part is, `any_exists` would contain `0` or `1` depending on results, the value is like binary digit for false or true. :-)

Answer (score 40):

```
#/bin/bash

myarray=(`find ./ -maxdepth 1 -name "*.py"`)
if [ ${#myarray[@]} -gt 0 ]; then 
    echo true 
else 
    echo false
fi
```

Comment: This one is nice because you can actually *do* something with the files after you find them.

Comment: +1 for wrapping subshell running find in parenthesis to make myarray an array variable. Otherwise, if find returns no result `${#myarray[@]}` equals 1

Comment: could also simplify by using `ls -1 *.py` instead of find

Comment: If any of the files have a space in the name, this will count one instance as two.

Comment: +1 as this solution works even if there are very large numbers of .flac files (or .py files in this case), whereas solutions using `ls` don't work for large numbers of files.

Answer (score 20):

This uses ls(1), if no flac files exist, ls reports error and the script exits; othewise the script continues and the files may be be processed

```
#! /bin/sh
ls *.flac  >/dev/null || exit
## Do something with flac files here
```

Comment: For extra silence, redirect 2>&1 as well.

Comment: The if version: `if ls *.flac >/dev/null  2>&1; then ... fi;`

Comment: Extra silence but more compact:  use `&> /dev/null` instead of `>/dev/null 2>&1` ;)

Answer (score 13):

```
shopt -s nullglob
if [[ -n $(echo *.flac) ]]    # or [ -n "$(echo *.flac)" ]
then 
    echo true
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to be carful which flag you throw into your `if` statement, and how it relates to the outcome you want.

If you want to check for **only regular files** and not other types of file system entries then you'll want to change your code skeleton to:

```
if [ -f file ]; then
echo true;
fi
```

The use of the `-f` restricts the `if` to regular files, whereas `-e` is more expansive and will match all types of filesystem entries.  There are of course other options like `-d` for directories, etc.  See http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/fto.html for a good listing.

As pointed out by @msw, `test` (i.e. `[`) will choke if you try and feed it more than one argument.  This might happen in your case if the glob for `*.flac` returned more than one file.  In that case try wrapping your `if` test in a loop like:

```
for file in ./*.pdf
do
    if [ -f "${file}" ]; then
    echo 'true';
    break
    fi
done
```

This way you `break` on the first instance of the file extension you want and can keep on going with the rest of the script.

Comment: except `test` (aka `[`) complains if the pattern expands to more than one file:  "binary operator expected" or "too many arguments"

Comment: @msw - thanks, I didn't even think of that issue. I've tried to modify my answer to take it into account.

Comment: You should quote the variable, i.e. use `"$file"`, because the filename may contain some bad characters, like spaces or asterisks.

Answer (score 4):

```
#!/bin/bash
files=$(ls /home/somedir/*.flac 2> /dev/null | wc -l)
if [ "$files" != "0" ]
then
echo "Some files exists."
else
echo "No files with that extension."
fi
```

Answer (score 4):

The top solution `(if [ -e *.flac ];)` did not work for me, giving: `[: too many arguments`

`if ls *.flac >/dev/null 2>&1;` then it will work.

Comment: That was the question, not the top solution

Answer (score 4):

You can use -f to check whether files of a specific type exist:

```
#!/bin/bash

if [ -f *.flac ] ; then
   echo true
fi
```

Comment: This works but you're burying the lede - the _reason_ it works is because the single-brace `[` (as opposed to the more common `[[`) doesn't prevent globbing.

Answer (score 3):

For completion, with zsh:

```
if [[ -n *.flac(#qN) ]]; then
  echo true
fi
```

This is listed at the end of the [Conditional Expressions](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Conditional-Expressions.html) section in the zsh manual. Since `[[` disables filename globbing, we need to force filename generation using `(#q)` at the end of the globbing string, then the `N` flag (`NULL_GLOB` option) to force the generated string to be empty in case there’s no match.

Answer (score 2):

```
   shopt -s nullglob
   set -- $(echo *.ext)
    if [ "${#}" -gt 0 ];then
      echo "got file"
    fi
```

Comment: This is wrong. First, you probably meant `-ge` instead of `-gt`, because otherwise your code won't detect the single file. Second, if there are no files matching the pattern, any conforming shell will left the string `*.ext` untouched, so you still will get one "result".

Comment: $# is 1 for a singe file and  0 for no files.

Answer (score 2):

bash only:

```
any_with_ext () ( 
    ext="$1"
    any=false
    shopt -s nullglob
    for f in *."$ext"; do
        any=true
        break
    done
    echo $any 
)

if $( any_with_ext flac ); then
    echo "have some flac"
else 
    echo "dir is flac-free"
fi
```

I use parentheses instead of braces to ensure a subshell is used (don't want to clobber your current `nullglob` setting).

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using no external commands (i.e. no `ls`), but a shell function instead.  Tested in bash:

```
shopt -s nullglob
function have_any() {
    [ $# -gt 0 ]
}

if have_any ./*.flac; then
    echo true
fi
```

The function `have_any` uses `$#` to count its arguments, and `[ $# -gt 0 ]` then tests whether there is at least one argument.  The use of `./*.flac` instead of just `*.flac` in the call to `have_any` is to avoid problems caused by files with names like `--help`.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a fairly simple solution:

`if [ "$(ls -A | grep -i \\.flac\$)" ]; then echo true; fi`

As you can see, this is only one line of code, but it works well enough. It should work with both bash, and a posix-compliant shell like dash. It's also case-insensitive, and doesn't care what type of files (regular, symlink, directory, etc.) are present, which could be useful if you have some symlinks, or something.

Comment: i like this because ls -AR does recursive search.  good for searching the contents of zip archives after unzipping.

Answer (score 1):

I tried this:

```
if [ -f *.html ]; then
    echo "html files exist"
else
    echo "html files dont exist"
fi
```

I used this piece of code without any problem for other files, but for html files I received an [error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781216/meaning-of-too-many-arguments-error-from-if-square-brackets):

```
[: too many arguments
```

I then tried @JeremyWeir's count solution, which worked for me:

```
count=`ls -1 *.flac 2>/dev/null | wc -l`
if [ $count != 0 ]
then 
echo true
fi
```

Keep in mind you'll have to reset the count if you're doing this in a loop:

```
count=$((0))
```

Comment: If there are more then one file with the given extension in the directory, *.html is expanding to too many arguments. Like "if [ -f file1.html file2.html ]; then"...

Answer (score 1):

This should work in any borne-like shell out there:

```
if [ "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f | grep -i '.*\.flac$')" ]; then
    echo true
fi
```

This also works with the GNU `find`, but IDK if this is compatible with other implementations of `find`:

```
if [ "$(find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname \*.flac)" ]; then
    echo true
fi
```