# How to perform an action only when a newer file was downloaded by wget or curl?

Tags: bash, curl, wget

I am looking for a simple bash solution to perform an action when a file is updated after a command like `wget --timestamp https://example.com/my.file`

I observed that wget returns 0 on both case, when the files is already latest version and also when it did download a newer one.

What's the easiest way to implement this in bash?

Comment: Save as a different file then compare them, if they are different then do whatever

Comment: @JID I would rather save the datetime of the file in a variable before running wget and checking it after the execution. I don't want to add new files to the disk for no good reason.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is for no good reason as it solves your problem. Depending on the size of the file, it would probably be on the disk for less than a few seconds. You could also use `-qO-` and compare the stdout that this produces against the original.Or you could save the datetime into a variable as you have said, although i don't know what the point of the question is in that case.

Comment: If the remote file supports HTTP HEAD, use `curl -I https://example.com/my.file` and compare the timestamp on your local file with the `Last-Modified` header value of the remote file

Comment: You can use `inotifywait` to check for file changes.

Comment: Can you check if my answer is correct?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `stat -c %y` to save the timestamp of the last data modification, before and after the execution of `wget`. Then run your action if the two timestamps are different.

```
t1=$(stat -c %y $FILE)
wget https://example.com/$FILE
t2=$(stat -c %y $FILE)
if [ "$t1" != "$t2" ]; then
   echo "Do something"
fi
```

If you are using a BSD-like Unix such as macos use `stat -f %m` instead of `stat -c %y`.

Comment: Great workarround... Side note: This will produce `[: too many arguments` error. (stat timestamp has spaces). Use double square brackets or double quotes... See http://stackoverflow.com/a/13781217/1601332

Comment: Thanks for your remark, I've modified my answer accordingly.