# How to propagate the core.sshCommand option to submodule update?

Tags: git, ssh, git-submodules, ssh-keys

I've set the `core.sshCommand` option for a repo so that I could use a different ssh key when working with it (i.e. `sshCommand = ssh -i /path/to/key`). However, when I run `git submodule update` this option is not considered:

```
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Is there any way I can configure the repo to use the given ssh key for itself and any submodules?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: @ArkaPravaBasu Did my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63300000/5337834) help?

Comment: Hello @JohnStrood, I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2419609/5285588) to solve this.

Comment: @ArkaPravaBasu Yes, you can do that too, but that won't help you if you want to set it locally, like if you want to clone different repos to different github accounts.

Comment: @ArkaPravaBasu Although you can ask ssh to try all keys in succession. It would be more elegant to set the env `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` when you pull/push.

Comment: Reading the git [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-coresshCommand) it would seem you can only use `core.sshCommand` for `git fetch` and `git push`.

Answer (score 8):

Either set it globally:

```
git config --global core.sshCommand "ssh -i /path/to/key"
```

But that sets the key for every repository you work with.

Or set it for every submodule:

```
git submodule foreach git config core.sshCommand "ssh -i /path/to/key"
```

Comment: Not working for me. Unable to add a submodule as it is picking the wrong ssh key

Comment: `git submodule foreach` runs through the existing submodules. For a new submodule just being added you need something like `git -c core.sshCommand="ssh -i /path/to/key" submodule add`

Answer (score 3):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49502090/5337834), from where I pulled this quote,

> The `core.sshCommand` option was added to git 2.10.0. You're running 2.7.4, which doesn't have that functionality. You'd need to upgrade to a newer Git if you wanted to use it.

If you are running a very old version, be mindful of the changes. You can consult this [changelog](https://github.com/git/git/blob/master/Documentation/RelNotes/2.10.0.txt#L83).

You can use the environmental variable `GIT_SSH_COMMAND` instead.

```
export GIT_SSH_COMMAND="/usr/bin/ssh -i /your/path/to/id_rsa"
```