# ERROR: Repository not found. fatal: Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the correct access rights and repo exists

Tags: git, github, ssh

Yesterday I created a ssh key and cloned a repo for work. After making some changes I attempted to push a commit:

```
git push
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

[I have read this active SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13509293/git-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository). My issue persists. I don't know how to track down the issue so will share everything that I think is relevant.

On my laptop I have both personal and work repos. My work work lives in any directory nested under `~/Documents/Projects/Zen/Projects/`. Anywhere else e.g. `~/Documents/Projects/Personal/` is for personal github.

My .gitconfig looks like this:

```
[user]
    email = 12345+doug@users.noreply.github.com
    name = 12345doug

[includeIf "gitdir:/home/doug/Documents/Projects/Zen/"]
    path = ~/.git-zen
```

/.git-zen looks like this:

```
[user]
        email = doug@work.com
        name = doug-work
```

Currently I'm in a repo:

```
pwd
/home/doug/Documents/Projects/Zen/Projects/analytics-psql-action
```

With some commits ready to push:

```
~/Documents/Projects/Zen/Projects/analytics-psql-action$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 2 commits.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
```

My git config in this dir seems correct:

```
git config user.name
doug-work
```

and

```
git config user.email
doug@work.com
```

To create my ssh keys I followed [this post](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent) on github.com.

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "doug@work.com"
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add ~/.ssh/id_rsa
```

I then added the key per [this tutorial](https://docs.github.com/en/github-ae@latest/authentication/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account) to my work github settings.

So far I *think* I have everything set up as it should? But when I try to push from within this repo:

```
~/Documents/Projects/Zen/Projects/analytics-psql-action$ git push
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

In desperation I renamed the repo and attempted to clone from fresh:

```
git clone git@github.com:work/analytics-psql-action.git # real path actually used not 'work'
Cloning into 'analytics-psql-action'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
```

On the repo itself, if I go into repo settings > manage access I can see myself, doug-work has admin access rights.

How can I clone and push to the repo? Where should I start in trying to find out why my set up of ssh keys are not working?

Comment: I'm having the same problem; `ERROR: Repository not found.` is triggered because the repository is private. I don't know why using an alternate SSH identity causes a problem here, or how to fix it.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/61150726/266747; there are some strategies for associating `user.email` with a given ssh IdentityFile. I would also suggest adding `IdentitiesOnly=yes` for a given `Host` entry in `~/.ssh/config`, this will keep ssh from trying other identities.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

First, a bit of background: in the URL you use here:

```
git clone git@github.com:...
```

the only really significant part for this problem is the `git@github.com` part.  You can also spell this:

```
git clone ssh://git@github.com/...
```

(using exactly the same rest-of-text in place of `...`) with the exact same effect.

Next, to *diagnose the issue*, you want to run `ssh` from the command line:

```
ssh -T git@github.com
```

Had your URL said `git@corp.com` you'd want to run `ssh -T git@corp.com` here, and so on.  That is, we take the `user@host` part and run `ssh -T user@host`.  This makes this work for various company-hosted offshoot variants, not just GitHub.  It also lets us use more than one login *on* GitHub: see more below.

Now, having run `ssh -T git@github.com` you could get a permission denied error, meaning that *none* of the keys you tried over at github.com worked, or you could get this kind of output:

```
Hi M! You've successfully authenticated, but but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

(Here, we've authenticated ourselves to GitHub as M, head of the James Bond spy division.)

Now, if M has permission to access (read and write) the repositories, we'll be able to read and write the repositories.  But maybe M only has *read* access, and it's actually *Q* who has write access.  We stole both M's and Q's keys, but how do we get in as Q?

Before we get to that point, let's see what to do if this kind of authentication *fails entirely*.  Our next step is to run:

```
ssh -Tv git@github.com
```

This produces a *lot* output, all prefixed with `debug1`.  There may be some clues here as to what has gone wrong.  If not, we can use `ssh -Tvv`, or `ssh -Tvvv`, to get even more debug output, prefixed with `debug2` and `debug3`.  The usual suspects here when looking through all this output are to make sure that ssh is looking at the correct `.ssh/*` *files*, in which your ssh keys are stored.  Make sure that:

- ssh has the right path;
- ssh tries the right files therein; and
- it can actually *read* these files.

If not, look for your OS-specific methods for giving ssh the right permissions and/or paths.

#### Using multiple identities

As the evil spy breaking into the MI-5 records, we have compromised the secret keys of both M and Q, and [we now wish to insert our Trojan horse into the system so that we can attempt an overly elaborate death for James Bond](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gb428ySuFjA).  But that's for later: for now, we're getting in as M, but we need to get in as Q.  What *shall* we do?

In order to get in to GitHub as *Q* instead of *M*, we need to *configure ssh correctly*.  The reason is simple: just listing all our keys in our `.ssh` directory doesn't work.  ssh tries them in some order, and clearly, our ssh is trying our *M* key first.  As soon as that works, it's in, and ssh stops trying further keys.

We need to have our ssh try our *Q* key first.  We could *remove* our key for M, but that is annoying: now we can plant our Trojan horse, but we can't find Bond's current assignment, which is only readable by M.  What we'd *like* to have is a way to *pick which key we'll try*.

This is where the `.ssh/config` file comes in:

```
Host as-q
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/stolen-q-key

Host as-m
    Hostname github.com
    User git
    IdentitiesOnly yes
    IdentityFile ~/.ssh/stolen-m-key
```

Now we can list our two repositories as `ssh://as-m/mi5/bond-assignments.git` and `ssh://as-q/mi5/spy-devices.git`, or `as-m:mi5/bond-assignments.git` and `as-q:mi5/spy-devices.git`.  (That is, once you get *this* part working, you'll need to update the URLs associated with your clones.  Use `git remote set-url origin new-url` or `git config --edit` or whatever your favorite way is to achieve this.)

When we `ssh as-q`, we'll have ssh connect to github.com (`Hostname`), use `git` as the user name, and use the stolen Q key as the key.  When we `ssh as-m`, we'll connect to the same host and use the same user, but use the stolen *M* key this time.

#### I did all that and ssh works but Git-for-Windows still doesn't

You've run into one other problem:

- Old versions of Windows came with no, or an inadequate, ssh.
- So Git-for-Windows bundles an ssh (in the same way that it bundles a version of bash: git-bash isn't really *part of* Git, it's just needed to *use* Git, and the bundled ssh isn't part of Git either, it's just need to *use* Git).
- But the bundled ssh and the system ssh are *different versions* that use *different config files*.

If the system ssh works fine, tell Git to use the system ssh, e.g., `git config --global core.sshCommand ssh`.  If it's inadequate, use the bundled ssh (but then how did your testing above work?).

Comment: In `.ssh/config` you have `as-m` and `as-q`. Now I'm in my repo with commits to push. How can I tell git which config to use? As opposed to just `git push` do I need to add e.g. `git push as-m`?

Comment: When I run `ssh -T git@github.com` from within the work repo, I get "Hi 12345doug! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access." it looks like it's using my personal git credentials and not my work one `doug-work`. Perhaps my includeif is off?

Comment: Some more info. From within the work repo when I go `git config user.name` I do see the correct work user name `doug-work` and not personal `12345doug`

Comment: Finally got this working. Had to update the origin and replace `git@github.com` with the desired config e.g. `as-m` or `as-q` based on config examples above. Full example, suppose the origin is `git@github.com:ourcompany/myrepo.git` then change with `git remote set-url origin as-m:ourcompany/myrepo.git`

Comment: Note that `user.name` and `user.email` are *not used during authentication*. They are used much earlier, when you make new commits. It's the *host name* in the ssh URL that makes ssh look at the `.ssh/config`, and it's the `.ssh/config` that controls which key(s) ssh will send.

Comment: What **is** used during authentication?   
I'm getting the wrong user name come up there (and it isn't the user.name of my git config), and I suspect that is the problem - but where do I set what username is used for the SSH ?

Answer (score 2):

Try this if you are still facing issue even after adding SSH key.

> git remote -v

This will show you the remote SSH URL then,

> git remote set-url origin "SSHURL"

Paste the URL in the above line where SSHURL is.