# Personal access token path to file with pw instead of pw itself?

Tags: git, github, ssh, personal-access-token

[After failing to get set up with ssh keys](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69645366/error-repository-not-found-fatal-could-not-read-from-remote-repository-pleas?) I have now set up a personal access token to use with our github account.

I saved the PAT in `/.ssh/my_pat`.

This works in the terminal. If e.g. I type 'git push' I'm prompted for my username and and then password. If I type these in the commits are pushed to github.

My question is, can I pass a link tot he file containing the pw rather than having to type the contents of that file, the pw, each time?

Comment: Would something like this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35942754/how-can-i-save-username-and-password-in-git

Comment: Yes this looks like what I need! I will try when I get home