How to change the account I want to push from to git?
I recently met again with the problem of sublime merge wanting to push from a wrong account.
So here is the scenario:
I am on github I have created a repository with profile "x", but whenever I want to push anything from visual studio code or sublime merge it wants to push from profile "z".
I know I used my school login for "z" the first when it prompted me to login so I could start pushing things, but I never have actually found how to change it. I installed sublime merge with the hopes that I would not run in to this problem again, but it automatically uses the school login.

What do you mean? Git doesn't push "from" or "to" an account. Git knows about remotes (the location of another git repo), who authored a commit, and who committed a commit. SSH/HTTPS does the auth for pushing/pulling, not git.

Ok, where do I change the SSH/HTTPS info then?

Depends on which you use. SSH: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29023532/how-do-i-use-multiple-ssh-keys-on-github HTTPS https://docs.github.com/en/account-and-profile/setting-up-and-managing-your-personal-account-on-github/managing-your-personal-account/managing-multiple-accounts

Git doesn't operate on Github accounts. It operates on remotes. Here's a quick rundown on working with remotes.
View your remote URLs using git remote -v:
$ git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls.git (push)

Note that origin is an arbitrary remote name. It could be called anything†, origin is just the default.
Change the remote URL using git remote set-url:
$ git remote set-url origin git@github.com:h3xx/mbedtls

You don't have to have just one remote, either!
$ git remote add me git@github.com:h3xx/mbedtls
$ git remote -v
me      git@github.com:h3xx/mbedtls (fetch)
me      git@github.com:h3xx/mbedtls (push)
origin  https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls.git (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/ARMmbed/mbedtls.git (push)

When you add a remote, make sure you run git fetch <remote name>, or git fetch --all to fetch from every remote in your local repo.

Common misconception: Let's be accurate here. Adding a remote does NOT modify anything on GitHub. It only modifies settings in your local copy of the repo. Edit the file .git/config to see how your local copy is configured.

You can view branches and what remotes they track using git branch -vv:
$ git branch -vv
* (HEAD detached at mbedtls-3.4.1) 72718dd87 Merge pull request #1044 from Mbed-TLS/mbedtls-3.4.1rc0-pr
  development                      6d6c7982c [origin/development: behind 24633] Merge remote-tracking branch 'upstream-public/pr/1362' into development
  master                           edb8fec98 [origin/master: behind 3076] Add docs re Everest license

You can push a branch to a remote and set where it tracks from by using git push -u:
$ git push -u me master

Alternatively, without push -u, you can change the remote tracking branch of your local branches by running git branch --set-upstream-to=me/master:
$ git branch --set-upstream-to=me/master my-local-branch

† Git limits remote names to only being able to contain A-Z,a-z,0-9,-,.,,,/,_.
