# bash - "[: too many arguments" error in a while loop after an if

Tags: bash

First: I'm fairly new to bash batch-scripting but have experience in other script and programming languages

Second: I already looked at [Meaning of "[: too many arguments" error from if[] (square brackets)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13781216/meaning-of-too-many-arguments-error-from-if-square-brackets) but this that was not the solution for my problem.

I'm creating a command-line parser in a bash script. My first attempt actually already works but still has some if-statement code-duplication in the main-loop which I want to solve, so I moved it to the actual parsing-function and then I run into a "[: too many arguments" error which I cannot get solved (adding "" around variables did not work) in a piece of code which does work if I do not move the if.

Note: in the actual code there is one more command-line option, I left that out for 2 reasons:

1. shorter listing
2. error is seen on all options

The working code looks like this:

```sh
    arg_str = $@
    args=("$@")
    arglen=$#

    target=some_filename.txt
    in_dir=/some_input_dir/

    function working_parser()
    {
        local option=$1
        myresult=''

        i=0

        while [ ${args[i]} != $option -a $i -n $arglen ]
        do
            i=$((i+1))
        done
        #TODO add check on $i>arglen
        myresult=${args[$((i+1))]}
    }

    if [[ $arg_str == *'-t'* ]]; then
        working_function '-t'
    fi
    if [[ $myresult != '' ]]; then
        target=$myresult
    fi


    if [[ $arg_str == *'-i'* ]]; then
        working_function '-i'
    fi
    if [[ $myresult != '' ]]; then
        in_dir=$myresult
    fi
```

The failing code looks like this (Left out the definitions, since they are the same as for the working code).
The '[: too many arguments' error occurs in the while loop, where it did not happen in that same code in the working-version.

```sh
    function failing_parser()
    {
        local option=$1
        myresult=''

        if [[ $arg_str == *$option* ]]; then
            i=0

            while [ ${args[i]} != $option -a $i -n $arglen ]
            do
                i=$((i+1))
            done
            #TODO add check on $i>arglen
            myresult=${args[$((i+1))]}
        fi
    }

    failing_parser '-t'
    if [[ $myresult != '' ]]; then
        target=$myresult
    fi

    failing_parser '-i'   
    if [[ $myresult != '' ]]; then
        in_dir=$myresult
    fi
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Quotes! `while [ "${args[i]}" != "$option" -a "$i" -n "$arglen" ]`

Comment: I tried quotes and it does not work. Still keep getting the same issue. (Actually used the same line as Kamil suggests)
/*edit*/ now even tried it with quotes around the variables in both the if and while loop

Comment: `-n` is unary, not a binary, operator; `"$i" -n "$arglen"` is an invalid expression. What are you actually trying to *do*? Note also that `-a` for logical AND is considered obsolete; use `[ ... ] && [ ... ]` instead, or use `[[ ... && ... ]]`.

Comment: Did you mean `-ne` instead of `-n`?

Comment: @Nemelis, if quoting doesn't fix your *whole* problem, that's still not a reason not to quote. The code is even more broken without quoting than it is *with* quoting, insofar as without quoting you have additional bugs that show up when your values don't string-split and glob to the expected number of words (presumably one per expansion, but unless you quote that isn't a guarantee).

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: I did not mean that it was not a good comment. Just that I tried it and it did not work.

Comment: @chepner: I tried to check if i is not equal to arglen. I now see the mistake (I even made it twice when making the code-copy for here: Somehow the 'e' from '-ne' was removed when upgrading the function. I will use your comment about &&. Like I said I'm not that experienced with bash scripting and then google is your friend ;-).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are too many arguments because `-n` is unary operator, not a binary operator. Perhaps you mean `-ne`?

```
while [ "${args[i]}" != "$option" -a "$i" -ne "$arglen" ]
```

`-a` is considered nonportable and obsolete; it's better to use two separate `[` commands joined by `&&` instead:

```
while [ "${args[i]}" != "$option" ] && [ "$i" -ne "$arglen" ]
```

However, since you are already using one `bash`-specific feature (arrays), you may as well use `[[ ... ]]` as well:

```
while [[ "${args[i]}" != "$option" && "$i" -ne "$arglen" ]]
```

or even an arithmetic command:

```
while [[ "${args[i]}" != "$option" ]] && (( i != arglen ));
```

Comment: First saw your comment above and already reacted over there. Thank you for your help.

Comment: After I wrote the comment, I realized the assumption was probably safe enough to go ahead with an answer :)