# shell script - too many arguments

Tags: shell, if-statement

I am unsure what is causing this error. Script continues to run and enters the "if" statement without issues.

"./test.sh: line 79: [: too many arguments"

```
if [ grep -Fq "variable=00000000000" /home/me/test.txt ] ; then             #line 79
             ........
             ........
else
             echo "hi"
fi
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/13781216/6862601

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[ ... ]` is not part of the syntax of an `if` statement. `[` is a command name, that requires a final argument of `]` to simulate the *look* of syntax.
Drop them if you want to run a different command whose exit status `if` should check.

```
if grep -Fq "..." /honme/me/test.txt; then
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply use :

```
if grep -Fq "variable=00000000000" /home/me/test.txt; then
[...]
```

or

```
grep -Fq "variable=00000000000" /home/me/test.txt && echo 'true'
```

## Explanations

Every command have a return code that you can display with :

```
true
echo $? # return 0, true in bash
false
echo $? # return 1: false in bash
```

It's named *boolean logic*